# Postgres reporting "window function call requires an OVER clause" in a query that has an OVER clause

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, window-functions

I've got a table, `me`, that's got an `e_id` column, a `first_name`, and a `last_name`. (A few other columns too but I'm just trying to figure out the window function stuff.)  When I try to do a query and pick out the first name values in the table for a given `e_id` value:

```
SELECT e_id, first_value(first_name), first_value(last_name)
  OVER (PARTITION BY e_id)
  FROM me
```

I get the "window function call requires an OVER clause" error. Now, like I said, I don't know what I'm doing yet, but I'm pretty sure there's at least an attempt at an OVER clause in that query. OK, so when I try it without the functions:

```
SELECT e_id, first_name, last_name
  OVER (PARTITION BY e_id)
  FROM me
```

I get a syntax error at OVER.  I'm running `psql` version 9.4.4 against a 9.1.13 server. I'm staring at the documentation for 9.1 and it looks to me like OVER is documented there. Am I just missing something basic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each window function must have its own `OVER` clause. The problem with your first query is that the `first_value(first_name)` window function does not have an `OVER` clause.

And the problem with your second query is that you have an `OVER` clause that is not preceded by a window function.

Try this

```
SELECT e_id, 
  first_value(first_name) OVER (PARTITION BY e_id), 
  first_value(last_name) OVER (PARTITION BY e_id)
FROM me
```

Comment: Ah. OK well that makes sense. Well it does now that I know it :)  Thanks!!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem but my query have `GROUP BY` clause. I've tried `OVER` query and it works but fails when grouping. The queries compute many stats so I cannot really switch to `OVER` from `GROUP BY`.